# Templating "Meta-Element" in Polymer - performance

Tags: performance, templates, polymer

i have a polymer element which has some templates and other elements inside of it. I can decide which kind of item will be displayed (either an item, checkbox, input or button) bin binding to a template. I use this so I can generate custom Events which have the same syntax across all used elements and some other things. I also have just this element instead of making millions of extends and seperate elements.

My Question is: Is this performant? Using templates like this, all across the app?

```
....
    <template id="aInput">
        <paper-input required="{{isRequired}}" 
                     value="{{label}}" 
                     flex>
            <content></content>
        </paper-input> 
    </template>

    <template id="aCheckbox">
        <paper-checkbox on-change="{{checkEvent}}" 
                        checked="{{isChecked}}">
            <content></content>
        </paper-checkbox>{{label}}
    </template>

    <template id="{{aIcon}}">
        <core-icon icon="{{icon}}" 
                   style="width: 32px; height: 32px;"></core-icon>
    </template>

    <template bind ref="{{aTemplate}}">
        <!-- Item -->
    </template>
```

.....

```
  tapEvent : function () 
            {
                // Event shall be not fired if the item ignores Fire
                if (!this.ignoreFire && (this.aTemplate === 'aItem' || this.aTemplate ===  'aButton')) 
                {
                    this.fire(this.eventhandler, 
                    {
                        'label'         : this.label,
                        'itemid'        : this.itemid,
                        'link'          : this.link,
                        'ability'       : this.ability,
                        'isButton'      : this.isButton,
                        'eventhandler'  : this.eventhandler,
                        'icon'          : this.icon,
                        'reference'     : this
                    });
                }
            },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its old and possibly outdated but we ditched this template. The reason is (or was) an endless amount of imports and thus a growing shadowDOM which would slow down the overall site. Especially for low-speed mobile devices the time it would take to make the http calls and the time of rendering it all increased with usage of this component. After Vulcanizing and ditching this meta-element, rendering time decreased and data transmitted was reduced, thus reducing loading times and get calls even further.